# If statement to change new row added to quantity added

Tags: javascript, html, shopping-cart

Hello I'm fairly new here so please correct me if I make any formatting or question errors!

I am attempting to create a simple shopping basket file and need some help getting the quantity of items within the basket to change. At the moment I can create a button that adds a new row to a table and fills it, I am just having a shortfall at getting the function to check if the item is already in the table and only update the quantity cell if it is. I am useless with IF statements, so any help would be more than appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function additem1() {

    var table = document.getElementById("basket");
    var row1 = table.insertRow(1);
    var cell1 = row1.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row1.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row1.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row1.insertCell(3);
    var cell5 = row1.insertCell(4);
    var cell6 = row1.insertCell(5);
cell1.innerHTML = "Shorts (f)";
cell2.innerHTML = "Stone Wash";
cell3.innerHTML = "1";
cell4.innerHTML = "";
cell5.innerHTML = "";
cell6.innerHTML = "";
;

}
</script>
<style>
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2> List of Items </h2>
    <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th> Product </th>
        <th> Description </th>
        <th> Quantity </th>
        <th> Price </th>

            <tr>
    <td> Shorts (F) </td>
    <td> Stone wash Denim shorts </td>
    <td> 20 </td>
    <td> 25.90 </td>
    <td> <button onclick= "additem1()"> Add Item To Basket </button> </td>

     </table>
```

```
     <table id="basket" border = "1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th> Product </th>
        <th> Description </th>
        <th> Quantity </th>
        <th> Price </th>
        <th colspan="2"> Add / Remove items </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

as you can see the first table holds the item information, and the second table holds the basket information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider to go deep on js coding; you can consider to check if the element already exist, then if so increment  the quantity.

I made your code a little more generic, but for a working basket there is more to do, that's your job.

Code:

```
function additem1(e) {
    var oRow = e.parentNode.parentNode
    var prod = oRow.cells[0].innerHTML;
    var des = oRow.cells[1].innerHTML;
    var table = document.getElementById("basket");

    var row1 = GetCellValues(prod);
    if (typeof row1 === 'undefined') {
        row1 = table.insertRow(1);
        var cell1 = row1.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row1.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row1.insertCell(2);
        var cell4 = row1.insertCell(3);
        var cell5 = row1.insertCell(4);
        var cell6 = row1.insertCell(5);
        cell1.innerHTML = prod;
        cell2.innerHTML = des;
        cell3.innerHTML = "1";
        cell4.innerHTML = "";
        cell5.innerHTML = "";
        cell6.innerHTML = "";;
    } else {
        row1.cells[2].innerHTML = parseInt(row1.cells[2].innerHTML) + 1
    }

}

function GetCellValues(prod) {
    var table = document.getElementById('basket');
    for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
        for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
            if (table.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML == prod) return table.rows[r];
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/85o9yz02/